# LetsEncrypt error: "Invalid response from http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge"

Tags: web-hosting, wordpress, lets-encrypt

Got a server running with the following: Vestacp, Nginx, Let's Encrypt, PHP-fpm, @ DigitalOcean.

I have around 10 WP sites currently running on it, and so far I have had no problems at all enabling SSL. But all of sudden I get this error when trying to enable Let's Encrypts SSL:

> Invalid response from `http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge`

I found a couple a threads mentioning that I could be because I was missing a file `Letsencrypt.pipe` - and I could not find the file, so I followed the instructions and created where it was supposed to be - and it seemed to work great for the next website I enabled Let's Encrypt on.
But now 2 sites later, I'm again unable to enable SSL and get that error again.

Comment: From the sounds of it, it's unable to access a required config file. This is either a permissions error or the file doesn't exist. Using lets encrypt auto, you should have all your domain configs ready in Nginx and then run it. It does a validation test at the end of setup when you request the certificates for your domain/subdomain names. Is this error during setup or after?

Comment: What plugin method are you using?   Are you using the nginx plugin, standalone, or webroot?

Comment: Have you tried reissuing the certificates?

Comment: Also posted there https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/invalid-response-from-http-example-com-well-known-acme-challeng/32741 and there https://www.reddit.com/r/letsencrypt/comments/67f3aj/invalid_response_from/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i ended up figuring this out myself, and sadly it was a "dumb" mistake that was the cause of this - and it only took 5 hours.
The guy who setup the domain, and installed the site - had forgot to change the DNS :)